# Prevent Expression Blend from loading every system font on startup

Tags: performance, fonts, expression-blend

After I reboot my machine, Microsoft Expression Blend 4 spends about 10 minutes loading every single font in `C:\Windows\Fonts` into some font cache (I determined this by watching its activity using [Procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645)). The application is unusable until this rather pointless operation completes. Is there any way to tweak Blend to stop it from doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Doubtful.  Whenever you have a text based property, you can change the font of that text in Blend.  To do so, you get a list of fonts with each font name rendered in that font.  Seems like you would need all of the fonts in the cache to be able to perform this operation.